# Start a CI calculation from HF/DFT chkfile in PySCF

Tags: density-functional-theory, python, pyscf, configuration-interaction

I am trying to perform a CISD calculation in PySCF using the starting orbitals from an old DFT result.

The DFT result was saved on a chkfile, `mf.hdf5`. The code that generate this file is the following:

```
import pyscf.gto, pyscf.dft

bz_geom="""\
C    -1.21225309     0.69989455     0.00000000;
C    -1.21225309    -0.69989455     0.00000000;
C    -0.00000000    -1.39978909     0.00000000;
C     1.21225309    -0.69989455     0.00000000;
C     1.21225309     0.69989455     0.00000000;
C     0.00000000     1.39978909     0.00000000;
H    -2.15365863     1.24341536     0.00000000;
H    -2.15365863    -1.24341536     0.00000000;
H    -0.00000000    -2.48683071     0.00000000;
H     2.15365863    -1.24341536     0.00000000;
H     2.15365863     1.24341536     0.00000000;
H     0.00000000     2.48683071     0.00000000"""

mol = pyscf.gto.M(atom=bz_geom, basis='bfd_vtz', ecp='bfd')
mf  = pyscf.dft.RKS(mol)
mf.xc='b3lyp'
mf.chkfile="mf.hdf5"
mf.kernel()
```

It was very difficult to me finding documentation about how to load information from a chkfile. I came across with the function `pyscf.scf.chkfile.load_scf`. However, when I try to use it to perform the CI calculation, I get an error:

```
import pyscf.gto, pyscf.dft, pyscf.ci, pyscf.scf

mf = pyscf.scf.chkfile.load_scf('mf.hdf5')

# CISD calculation
cisolver = pyscf.ci.CISD(mf)
cisolver.kernel()
```

The full error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20980/4228492657.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # CISD calculation
---> 24 cisolver = pyscf.ci.CISD(mf)
     25 cisolver.kernel()
     26 

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscf/ci/__init__.py in CISD(mf, frozen, mo_coeff, mo_occ)
     31         return UCISD(mf, frozen, mo_coeff, mo_occ)
     32     else:
---> 33         return RCISD(mf, frozen, mo_coeff, mo_occ)
     34 CISD.__doc__ = cisd.CISD.__doc__
     35 

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscf/ci/__init__.py in RCISD(mf, frozen, mo_coeff, mo_occ)
     38 
     39     if isinstance(mf, newton_ah._CIAH_SOSCF) or not isinstance(mf, scf.hf.RHF):
---> 40         mf = scf.addons.convert_to_rhf(mf)
     41 
     42     if getattr(mf, 'with_df', None):

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscf/scf/addons.py in convert_to_rhf(mf, out, remove_df)
    692     from pyscf import scf
    693     from pyscf import dft
--> 694     assert (isinstance(mf, hf.SCF))
    695 
    696     logger.debug(mf, 'Converting %s to RHF', mf.__class__)

AssertionError:
```

It seems to me that the error is because the mf object is from a DFT calculation and not from a HF calculation. I get a similar error before (if I try to start the CI calculation directly from the DFT `mf` object, instead of with the chkfile). In that case, I got a helpful error message:

```
RuntimeError: CISD Warning: The first argument mf is a DFT object. CISD calculation should be initialized with HF object.
DFT object can be converted to HF object with the code below:
    mf_hf = scf.RHF(mol)
    if getattr(mf_dft, "with_x2c", False):
        mf_hf = mf_hf.x2c()
    mf_hf.__dict__.update(mf_dft.__dict__)
```

So I should try to do something similar with the `mf` object obtained from `pyscf.scf.chkfile.load_scf`. The problem is I do not have the `mol` object in that case.

I probably am doing something wrong. What is the correct procedure to start a CI calculation from a previous chkfile from a DFT or HF calculation?

Comment: These two questions and their answers could provide direction for you.
[restarting-an-fci-calculation-in-pyscf](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/restarting-an-fci-calculation-in-pyscf) and [why-is-my-cisd-restart-failing-in-pyscf](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/why-is-my-cisd-restart-failing-in-pyscf)

Comment: @VandanRevanur I read those questions before writing mine. They are not related to my problem.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Have you seen this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10277/5 and this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10349/5? Less relevant but perhaps also interesting to you is this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10444/5. I was saving my HF information as a `.chk` file instead of a `.h5` or `.hdf5` file. Also, please show your input and full output. The fact that you deleted everything after "
AssertionError:" is surprising to me.

Comment: @NikeDattani I edited the question to include more info. I think none of those questions you linked are directly related to my issue, since they are about the chkfile from a CISD calculation, and not using a SCF chkfile to start a CISD calculation. Sometimes I find PySCF very confusing.

Comment: @DavidSousa Please take a more careful look at the questions that I provided in my last comment. Also, is there nothing that comes after `Assertion Error:`? It would be helpful if you could provide the whole output file. Questions can have up to 30,000 characters and if you exceed that limit, there's a GitHub repository for input/output files related to MMSE posts: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5

Comment: No, there is nothing else after `Assertion Error:`.

Comment: @NikeDattani The reason there is nothing after the AssertionError: is because there is no message coded in the pyscf to display in the line : `assert (isinstance(mf, hf.SCF))` which could have been better this way `assert (isinstance(my,hf.SCF), “the mf is not an instance of hf”.` The assertion Error would have then displayed that message. Since there is no message at the moment , nothing is displayed.

Comment: @DavidSousa in the questions I provided, post-HF calculations were done from a chkfile. Can you try what I did but with your chkfile, then we can consider how to change CCSD to CISD? Also, again I ask that you provide the input and output files. It seems that you've not provided the input file that leads to that error.

Comment: @NikeDattani I am sorry, I forgot to provide the full input of the second file. The first piece of code is (the most relevant part) a python script that performs the DFT calculation. I edited now to show the second piece of code as a separate python script that loads the result from the previous calculation. The full error messages are shown.

Comment: Are you able to do CCSD from the Kohn-Sham-SCF orbitals in the checkfile? My previous questions showed how to save an HF-SCF checkfile and then read it and do CCSD with the saved orbitals.

Comment: @NikeDattani if I understand right, it seems like in your question, the chkfile is generated and the post-SCF is made within the same script, and you do not load information directly from the chkfile, but from the mf object itself, which already exists in the script. My case is different, because the DFT calculation is already done, and I have only the chkfile.

Comment: If I try to do CCSD I get the exact same error.

Comment: @DavidSousa that is incorrect. Please read the questions all the way until the end.

Answer (score 3):

I got an [answer](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/1719) to this question at PySCF GitHub page from James E.T. Smith. I will post here in case someone has the same issue.

It can be done both ways:

```
import pyscf.scf, pyscf.ci

mol = pyscf.scf.chkfile.load_mol('mf.hdf5')
mf = pyscf.scf.RHF(mol) 
mf.__dict__.update(pyscf.scf.chkfile.load('mf.hdf5', 'scf')) 

cisolver = pyscf.ci.CISD(mf)
cisolver.kernel()
```

or

```
import pyscf.scf, pyscf.ci

mol, mf_dict = pyscf.scf.chkfile.load_scf('mf.hdf5')
mf = pyscf.scf.RHF(mol) 
mf.__dict__.update(mf_dict) 
cisolver = pyscf.ci.CISD(mf)
cisolver.kernel()
```